# Remove elements according to text content using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to delete table row (tr) elements that contain the word "Amend". How can I change the code below to make that happen?

```
for e in soup.findAll("tr"):
   e.extract()
```

*** Edit:

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
for e in soup.findAll('tr', text = re.compile('.*Amend.*')):
    e.extract()
```

*** Edit:

This is the page that I'm working on:

https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=AAON&type=10&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=40

Comment: There is no tr with amend, there is a `<td class="small"><b>[Amend]</b>`

Comment: One of the tr elements has a child with the term "amend", sorry I should have specified that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you find all nodes having `Amend`, go [up the tree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent) to the `tr` and remove:

```
for amend in soup.find_all(text=re.compile("Amend")):
    tr = amend.find_parent("tr")
    if tr:  # safety feature
        tr.extract()
```

Or, alternatively, you can use a [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
for tr in soup.find_all(lambda node: node and \
                                     node.name == "tr" and \
                                     node.find(text=re.compile("Amend"))):
    tr.extract()
```

Comment: I like your thinking, but its not working: This is the page that I am working on: https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=AAON&type=10&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=40